# How to plot histogram difference with seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I tried to make something like this

```
    data1 = get_data(param=param1)
    data2 = get_data(param=param2)
    plot1 = sns.histplot(data=data1, x="Value")
    plot2 = sns.histplot(data=data2, x="Value")
```

But couldn't manage to plot difference in count between `plot1` and `plot2`

Is there a way to do it with seaborn? Or is there some other library that will get the job done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you calculate the values with a numpy histogram and make a bar graph of the differences? `np.histogram(...)`

Comment: `sns.histplot(data={'data1': data1.Value.values, 'data2': data2.Value.values})` would show both at the same spot, with transparency showing the differences.